# how to revert android:sharedUserId change

Tags: android

I have an app in the play store (let's say version code 1.1) that is not using android:sharedUserId in the manifest.
I needed that users could share his data with another app, so I make a new version (the 1.2) using android:sharedUserId in the manifest, to allow that sharing.
This caused that when the users updated from 1.1 to 1.2 could not acces his data.

When I realised that problem quickly make a new version (1.3) removing the android:sharedUserId from the manifest, leaving it as it was in the first version.

Now I see that users that upgrade from 1.1 to 1.3 directly, has no problems and the app works well. But users that upgraded from 1.1 to 1.2 and then upgraded to 1.3, still have no acces to his data. For the readings I've done, I can understand that 1.2 can't acces the data since the user specified as sharedUserId is diferent from the one who created the directory in version 1.1. But in the 1.3 there's no android:sharedUserId (the manifest is the same that in version 1.1). So I can't understand why there's no acces.

Somebody can figure out which is the problem and how could it be solved?

Thank's

Comment: The moral of this story is that there are **MUCH** better ways of securing data transfer than by using `android:sharedUserId`.

Comment: The simple answer of "why" is because when you go from `sharedUserId` to no sharing, a new user id is allocated to your app, which will very unlikely be the same as the original user id for version 1.1